# How do I change tab url

Tags: plugins, php

I'm currently editing an affiliate plugin. I have added the affiliate plugin as a tab in 'My account' as well as using the plugin's shortcode to display the content there. Although when I click on the dropdown and select 'Today' for example, the page redirects to an URL without 'affiliate-area' in it, therefore the filter doesn't work. How can I edit this so the filter works?

Thanks.

Current webpage output on load:
[image]

webpage output when 'Today' is selected from dropdown and 'Filter' button is clicked:
[image]

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Graphs
 *
 * This class handles building pretty report graphs
 *
 * @package     AffiliateWP
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012, Pippin Williamson
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php GNU Public License
 * @since       1.0
 */

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

/**
 * Affiliate_WP_Graph Class
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
class Affiliate_WP_Graph {

    /*

    Simple example:

    data format for each point: array( location on x, location on y )

    $data = array(

        'Label' => array(
            array( 1, 5 ),
            array( 3, 8 ),
            array( 10, 2 )
        ),

        'Second Label' => array(
            array( 1, 7 ),
            array( 4, 5 ),
            array( 12, 8 )
        )
    );

    $graph = new Affiliate_WP_Graph( $data );
    $graph->display();

    */

    /**
     * Data to graph
     *
     * @var array
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public $data;

    /**
     * Unique ID for the graph
     *
     * @var string
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public $id = '';

    /**
     * Graph options
     *
     * @var array
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public $options = array();

    /**
     * Get things started
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function __construct( $_data = array() ) {

        $this->data = $_data;

        // Generate unique ID
        $this->id   = md5( rand() );

        // Setup default options;
        $this->options = array(
            'y_mode'          => null,
            'x_mode'          => null,
            'y_decimals'      => 0,
            'x_decimals'      => 0,
            'y_position'      => 'right',
            'time_format'     => '%d/%b',
            'ticksize_unit'   => 'day',
            'ticksize_num'    => 1,
            'multiple_y_axes' => false,
            'bgcolor'         => '#f9f9f9',
            'bordercolor'     => '#ccc',
            'borderwidth'     => 2,
            'bars'            => false,
            'lines'           => true,
            'points'          => true,
            'currency'        => true,
            'show_controls'   => true,
        );

    }

    /**
     * Set an option
     *
     * @param $key The option key to set
     * @param $value The value to assign to the key
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function set( $key, $value ) {
        if( 'data' == $key ) {

            $this->data = $_data;

        } else {

            $this->options[ $key ] = $value;

        }
    }

    /**
     * Get an option
     *
     * @param $key The option key to get
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function get( $key ) {
        return isset( $this->options[ $key ] ) ? $this->options[ $key ] : false;
    }

    /**
     * Get graph data
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function get_data() {
        return apply_filters( 'affwp_get_graph_data', $this->data, $this );
    }

    /**
     * Load the graphing library script
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function load_scripts() {
        // Use minified libraries if SCRIPT_DEBUG is turned off
        $suffix = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-flot', AFFILIATEWP_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js/jquery.flot' . $suffix . '.js' );

        if( $this->load_resize_script() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-flot-resize', AFFILIATEWP_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js/jquery.flot.resize' . $suffix . '.js' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the resize script should be loaded
     *
     * @since 1.1
     */
    public function load_resize_script() {

        $ret = true;

        // The DMS theme is known to cause some issues with the resize script
        if( defined( 'DMS_CORE' ) ) {
            $ret = false;
        }

        return apply_filters( 'affwp_load_flot_resize', $ret );
    }

    /**
     * Build the graph and return it as a string
     *
     * @var array
     * @since 1.0
     * @return string
     */
    public function build_graph() {
        $this->load_scripts();

        ob_start();

        if ( function_exists( 'wp_add_inline_script' ) ) {
            wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery-flot', $this->graph_js() );
        } else {
            // Back-compat for < WP 4.5.0.
            wp_scripts()->add_data( 'jquery-flot', 'after', array(
                wp_scripts()->get_data( 'jquery-flot', 'after' ),
                $this->graph_js()
            ) );
        }

        if ( false !== $this->get( 'show_controls' ) ) {
            echo $this->graph_controls();
        }
        ?><div id="affwp-graph-<?php echo $this->id; ?>" class="affwp-graph" style="height: 300px; width:100%;"></div><?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the Graph initialization JS for output inline.
     *
     * @access public
     * @since  1.9.5
     *
     * @return string Graph JS output.
     */
    public function graph_js() {
        $yaxis_count = 1;

        ob_start();
        ?>
        var affwp_vars;
        jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
            $.plot(
                $("#affwp-graph-<?php echo $this->id; ?>"),
                [
                    <?php foreach( $this->get_data() as $label => $data ) : ?>
                    {
                        label: "<?php echo esc_attr( $label ); ?>",
                        id: "<?php echo sanitize_key( $label ); ?>",
                        // data format is: [ point on x, value on y ]
                        data: [<?php foreach( $data as $point ) { echo '[' . implode( ',', $point ) . '],'; } ?>],
                        points: {
                            show: <?php echo $this->options['points'] ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
                        },
                        bars: {
                            show: <?php echo $this->options['bars'] ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
                            barWidth: 2,
                            align: 'center'
                        },
                        lines: {
                            show: <?php echo $this->options['lines'] ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
                        },
                        <?php if( $this->options[ 'multiple_y_axes' ] ) : ?>
                        yaxis: <?php echo $yaxis_count; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    },
                    <?php $yaxis_count++; endforeach; ?>
                ],
                {
                    // Options
                    grid: {
                        show: true,
                        aboveData: false,
                        backgroundColor: "<?php echo $this->options[ 'bgcolor' ]; ?>",
                        borderColor: "<?php echo $this->options[ 'bordercolor' ]; ?>",
                        borderWidth: <?php echo absint( $this->options[ 'borderwidth' ] ); ?>,
                        clickable: false,
                        hoverable: true
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        mode: "<?php echo $this->options['x_mode']; ?>",
                        timeFormat: "<?php echo $this->options['x_mode'] == 'time' ? $this->options['time_format'] : ''; ?>",
                        tickSize: "<?php echo $this->options['x_mode'] == 'time' ? '' : 1; ?>",
                        <?php if( $this->options['x_mode'] != 'time' ) : ?>
                        tickDecimals: <?php echo $this->options['x_decimals']; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        position: 'right',
                        min: 0,
                        mode: "<?php echo $this->options['y_mode']; ?>",
                        timeFormat: "<?php echo $this->options['y_mode'] == 'time' ? $this->options['time_format'] : ''; ?>",
                        <?php if( $this->options['y_mode'] != 'time' ) : ?>
                        tickDecimals: <?php echo $this->options['y_decimals']; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    }
                }

            );

            function affwp_flot_tooltip(x, y, contents) {
                $('<div id="affwp-flot-tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'none',
                    top: y + 5,
                    left: x + 5,
                    border: '1px solid #fdd',
                    padding: '2px',
                    'background-color': '#fee',
                    opacity: 0.80
                }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
            }

            var previousPoint = null;
            $("#affwp-graph-<?php echo $this->id; ?>").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
                $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
                if (item) {
                    if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                        $("#affwp-flot-tooltip").remove();
                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                        <?php if( $this->get( 'currency' ) ) : ?>
                        if( affwp_vars.currency_pos == 'before' ) {
                            affwp_flot_tooltip( item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + ' ' + affwp_vars.currency_sign + y );
                        } else {
                            affwp_flot_tooltip( item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + ' ' + y + affwp_vars.currency_sign );
                        }
                        <?php else : ?>
                        affwp_flot_tooltip( item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + ' ' + y );
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#affwp-flot-tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;
                }
            });

            $( '#affwp-graphs-date-options' ).change( function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if( $this.val() == 'other' ) {
                    $( '#affwp-date-range-options' ).css('display', 'inline-block');
                } else {
                    $( '#affwp-date-range-options' ).hide();
                }
            });

        });
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Output the final graph
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function display() {
        /**
         * Fires just prior to the graph output.
         *
         * @param stdClass $graph The graph object.
         */
        do_action( 'affwp_before_graph', $this );

        echo $this->build_graph();

        /**
         * Fires immediately after the graph output.
         *
         * @param stdClass $graph The graph object.
         */
        do_action( 'affwp_after_graph', $this );
    }

    /**
     * Show report graph date filters
     *
     * @since 1.0
     * @return void
    */
    function graph_controls() {
        $date_options = apply_filters( 'affwp_report_date_options', array(
            'today'         => __( 'Today', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'yesterday'     => __( 'Yesterday', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'this_week'     => __( 'This Week', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'last_week'     => __( 'Last Week', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'this_month'    => __( 'This Month', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'last_month'    => __( 'Last Month', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'this_quarter'  => __( 'This Quarter', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'last_quarter'  => __( 'Last Quarter', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'this_year'     => __( 'This Year', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'last_year'     => __( 'Last Year', 'affiliate-wp' ),
            'other'         => __( 'Custom', 'affiliate-wp' )
        ) );

        $dates = affwp_get_report_dates();

        $display = $dates['range'] == 'other' ? 'style="display:inline-block;"' : 'style="display:none;"';

        $current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );

        ?>
        <form id="affwp-graphs-filter" method="get">
            <div class="tablenav top">

                <?php if( is_admin() ) : ?>
                    <?php $tab = isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ? $_GET['tab'] : 'referral'; ?>
                    <?php $page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 'affiliate-wp'; ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $page ); ?>"/>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php $tab = isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ? $_GET['tab'] : 'graphs'; ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_ID() ); ?>"/>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="tab" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $tab ); ?>"/>

                <?php if( isset( $_GET['affiliate_id'] ) ) : ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="affiliate_id" value="<?php echo absint( $_GET['affiliate_id'] ); ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="view_affiliate"/>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <select id="affwp-graphs-date-options" name="range">
                <?php
                    foreach ( $date_options as $key => $option ) {
                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . selected( $key, $dates['range'] ) . '>' . esc_html( $option ) . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
                </select>

                <div id="affwp-date-range-options" <?php echo $display; ?>>

                    <?php
                    $from = empty( $_REQUEST['filter_from'] ) ? '' : $_REQUEST['filter_from'];
                    $to   = empty( $_REQUEST['filter_to'] )   ? '' : $_REQUEST['filter_to'];
                    ?>
                    <span class="affwp-search-date">
                        <span><?php _ex( 'From', 'date filter', 'affiliate-wp' ); ?></span>
                        <input type="text" class="affwp-datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="filter_from" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'From - mm/dd/yyyy', 'affiliate-wp' ); ?>" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'From - mm/dd/yyyy', 'affiliate-wp' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $from ); ?>" />
                        <span><?php _ex( 'To', 'date filter', 'affiliate-wp' ); ?></span>
                        <input type="text" class="affwp-datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="filter_to" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'To - mm/dd/yyyy', 'affiliate-wp' ); ?>" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'To - mm/dd/yyyy', 'affiliate-wp' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $to ); ?>" />
                    </span>

                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Filter', 'affiliate-wp' ); ?>"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }

}

/**
 * Sets up the dates used to filter graph data
 *
 * Date sent via $_GET is read first and then modified (if needed) to match the
 * selected date-range (if any)
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @return array
*/
function affwp_get_report_dates() {
    $dates = array();

    $current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );

    $dates['date_from']  = ! empty( $_REQUEST['filter_from'] ) ? $_REQUEST['filter_from'] : date( 'j/n/Y', $current_time );
    $dates['date_to']    = ! empty( $_REQUEST['filter_to'] )   ? $_REQUEST['filter_to']   : date( 'j/n/Y', $current_time );

    $variable_from_time  = ! empty( $_REQUEST['filter_from'] ) ? strtotime( $dates['date_from'] ) : $current_time;
    $variable_to_time    = ! empty( $_REQUEST['filter_to'] )   ? strtotime( $dates['date_to'] )   : $current_time;

    $dates['range']      = isset( $_GET['range'] )      ? $_GET['range']      : 'this_month';
    $dates['year']       = isset( $_GET['year_start'] ) ? $_GET['year_start'] : date( 'Y', $variable_from_time );
    $dates['year_end']   = isset( $_GET['year_end'] )   ? $_GET['year_end']   : date( 'Y', $variable_to_time );
    $dates['m_start']    = isset( $_GET['m_start'] )    ? $_GET['m_start']    : date( 'n', $variable_from_time );
    $dates['m_end']      = isset( $_GET['m_end'] )      ? $_GET['m_end']      : date( 'n', $variable_to_time );
    $dates['day']        = isset( $_GET['day'] )        ? $_GET['day']        : date( 'd', $variable_from_time );
    $dates['day_end']    = isset( $_GET['day_end'] )    ? $_GET['day_end']    : date( 'd', $variable_to_time );

    // Modify dates based on predefined ranges
    switch ( $dates['range'] ) :

        case 'this_month' :
            $dates['day']       = 1;
            $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, $dates['m_start'], date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
            $dates['m_start']   = date( 'n', $current_time );
            $dates['m_end']     = date( 'n', $current_time );
            $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );
        break;

        case 'last_month' :
            if( date( 'n' ) == 1 ) {
                $dates['day']     = 1;
                $dates['day_end'] = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 12, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start'] = 12;
                $dates['m_end']   = 12;
                $dates['year']    = date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1;
                $dates['year_end']= date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1;
            } else {
                $dates['day']     = 1;
                $dates['day_end'] = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, date( 'n' ) - 1, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start'] = date( 'n' ) - 1;
                $dates['m_end']   = date( 'n' ) - 1;
                $dates['year_end']= $dates['year'];
            }
        break;

        case 'today' :
            $dates['day']       = date( 'd', $current_time );
            $dates['day_end']   = date( 'd', $current_time );
            $dates['m_start']   = date( 'n', $current_time );
            $dates['m_end']     = date( 'n', $current_time );
            $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );
        break;

        case 'yesterday' :
            $month              = date( 'n', $current_time ) == 1 && date( 'd', $current_time ) == 1 ? 12 : date( 'n', $current_time );
            $days_in_month      = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
            $yesterday          = date( 'd', $current_time ) == 1 ? $days_in_month : date( 'd', $current_time ) - 1;
            $dates['day']       = $yesterday;
            $dates['day_end']   = $yesterday;
            $dates['m_start']   = $month;
            $dates['m_end']     = $month;
            $dates['year']      = $month == 1 && date( 'd', $current_time ) == 1 ? date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1 : date( 'Y', $current_time );
        break;

        case 'this_week' :
            $dates['day']       = date( 'd', $current_time - ( date( 'w', $current_time ) - 1 ) *60*60*24 ) - 1;
            $dates['day']      += get_option( 'start_of_week' );
            $dates['day_end']   = $dates['day'] + 6;
            $dates['m_start']   = date( 'n', $current_time );
            $dates['m_end']     = date( 'n', $current_time );
            $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );
        break;

        case 'last_week' :
            $dates['day']       = date( 'd', $current_time - ( date( 'w' ) - 1 ) *60*60*24 ) - 8;
            $dates['day']      += get_option( 'start_of_week' );
            $dates['day_end']   = $dates['day'] + 6;
            $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );

            if( date( 'j', $current_time ) <= 7 ) {
                $dates['m_start']   = date( 'n', $current_time ) - 1;
                $dates['m_end']     = date( 'n', $current_time ) - 1;
                if( $dates['m_start'] <= 1 ) {
                    $dates['year'] = date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1;
                    $dates['year_end'] = date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1;
                }
            } else {
                $dates['m_start']   = date( 'n', $current_time );
                $dates['m_end']     = date( 'n', $current_time );
            }
        break;

        case 'this_quarter' :
            $month_now = date( 'n', $current_time );
            $dates['day'] = 1;

            if ( $month_now <= 3 ) {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 4, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start']   = 1;
                $dates['m_end']     = 4;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );

            } else if ( $month_now <= 6 ) {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 7, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start']   = 4;
                $dates['m_end']     = 7;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );

            } else if ( $month_now <= 9 ) {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 10, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start']   = 7;
                $dates['m_end']     = 10;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );

            } else {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 1, date( 'Y', $current_time ) + 1 );
                $dates['m_start']   = 10;
                $dates['m_end']     = 1;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );
                $dates['year_end']  = date( 'Y', $current_time ) + 1;

            }
        break;

        case 'last_quarter' :
            $month_now = date( 'n' );
            $dates['day'] = 1;

            if ( $month_now <= 3 ) {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 9, date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1 );
                $dates['m_start']   = 10;
                $dates['m_end']     = 12;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1; // Previous year

            } else if ( $month_now <= 6 ) {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 3, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start']   = 1;
                $dates['m_end']     = 3;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );

            } else if ( $month_now <= 9 ) {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 6, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start']   = 4;
                $dates['m_end']     = 6;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );

            } else {

                $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 9, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
                $dates['m_start']   = 7;
                $dates['m_end']     = 9;
                $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );

            }
        break;

        case 'this_year' :
            $dates['day']       = 1;
            $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 12, date( 'Y', $current_time ) );
            $dates['m_start']   = 1;
            $dates['m_end']     = 12;
            $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time );
            $dates['year_end']  = date( 'Y', $current_time );
        break;

        case 'last_year' :
            $dates['day']       = 1;
            $dates['day_end']   = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, 12, date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1 );
            $dates['m_start']   = 1;
            $dates['m_end']     = 12;
            $dates['year']      = date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1;
            $dates['year_end']  = date( 'Y', $current_time ) - 1;
        break;

    endswitch;

    return apply_filters( 'affwp_report_dates', $dates );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A link to the affiliate area from the WooCommerce account page is being added in AffiliateWP 2.1.